# centering an img inside body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i wrote a simple html code to center an img inside html body, it works fine on windows with different browsers and on phone vertically only when i rotate the phone the img is not  resizing. the  main problem is  that when i open this site on mac the centering  dont  work with all browsers!!!
here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">
    <title>LaBera</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        body {
            background-image: url("img/pattern-small.png");
            background-repeat: repeat-x-y;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .centerimg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="centerimg">
            <img src="img/logo1300.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo" width="241px" height="400px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <img src="img/footerNoShadow.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Footer" height="66px">
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using the prefixes needed for `transform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<style>
html {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/pattern-small.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x-y;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.centerimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
```

Note the changes made to your transform property, the added prefixes are for browser support, this might resolve your issue

[image: Browser support]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table/table-cell approach.

The parent element (what ever that may be, a body in your case) has the `display` property of `table`. Be sure to set the dimensinos explicitly as `tables` only take up as much as their content provides by default.

From there, the child element (in your case an image) should be set have the follow:

`display: table-cell;`
`vertical-align: middle;`

In total:

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; // whatever you want
  height: 100%; // whatever you want
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-width: 100% // image is never larger than its parent and always responsive. 
}
```